# Prove that () is odd if and only if n is perfect square or twice a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What I know is to let $n > 1$ and $$n = p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$$

Comment: The very natural next step is to remember how to calculate $\sigma(n)$ by using your prime decomposition.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: $gcd(m,n)=1 \implies \sigma(mn)=\sigma(m) \cdot \sigma(n). \sigma(p^n)= \frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$ if $p$ is prime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $\sigma(n)$ is odd, $n$ is either a square or twice a square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523164/prove-that-if-sigman-is-odd-n-is-either-a-square-or-twice-a-square)

Answer (score 1):

Let n>1 and $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}...p_r^{k_r}$.
Then,$\sigma(n)= (1+p_1+p_1^2+...+p_1^{k_1})(1+p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{k_2})(1+p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{k_r})$ is odd.

Case 1: $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}...p_r^{k_r}$ such that $p_r\not =2.$
We now have, $$(1+p_1+p_1^2+...+p_1^{k_1}),(1+p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{k_2}),...,(1+p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{k_r})$$ are odd integers. And so, there exist natural numbers $s_1,s_2,...,s_i$ such that, $$(1+p_1+p_1^2+...+p_1^{k_1})=2s_1+1,(1+p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{k_2})=2s_2+1,...,(1+p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{k_r})=2s_i+1.$$ This implies that $$p_1+p_1^2+...+p_1^{k_1}=2s_1,p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{k_2}=2s_2,...,p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{k_r}=2s_i.$$ Thus,$p_1+p_1^2+...+p_1^{k_1},p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{k_2},...,p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{k_r}$ are even numbers. Also note that, by Euclid, if as many odd numbers as we please are added together, and their multitude is even, then the sum is even. We have that $k_1,k_2,...,k_r$ must be an even natural number which implies that $$(1+p_1+p_1^2+...+p_1^{k_1}),(1+p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{k_2}),...,(1+p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{k_r})$$ are odd numbers. Hence, each distinct prime factor must have an even power. In other words, it should be a perfect square.

Case II: $n=2^{k_1}p_1^{k_2}...p_r^{k_r}$

Suppose $n=2^{k_1}p_1^{k_2}...p_r^{k_r}.$Then,$(1+2+2^2+...+2^{k_1}),(1+p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{k_2}),...,(1+p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{k_r})$ are odd integers. We already know from previous case that the power of a distinct prime factor must be an even natural number so that $(1+p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{k_2}),...,(1+p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{k_r})$ are odd integers. Also, notice that $(1+2+2^2+...+2^{k_1})= 1+2(1+2^2+...+2^{k_1-1})$ is an odd number whether k_1 is odd or even. Moreover, if k_1 is odd, $$n=2^{k_1}p_1^{k_2}...p_r^{k_r}$$ is twice a perfect square and if k_1 is even $$n=2^{k_1}p_1^{k_2}...p_r^{k_r}$$ is a perfect square. This means that $$\sigma(n)=\sigma(2^{k_1}p_1^{k_2}...p_r^{k_r})$$ is either a perfect square or twice a perfect square whenever it contains a prime factor 2.

Therefore, $\sigma(n)$ is odd if n is a perfect square or twice a perfect square.

Let us now prove the converse.
Case 1:Suppose n be a perfect square such that $n=2^{2k_1}p_2^{2k_2}...p_r^{2k_r}$. Then, $$\sigma(n)=\sigma(2^{2k_1}p_2^{2k_2}...p_r^{2k_r})=(1+2+2^2+...+2^{2k_1})(1+p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{2k_2})...(1+p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{2k_r}).$$ We know that the powers of the distinct prime factors $2,p_2,...p_r$ goes from 1 to $2k_r$. This implies that the number of terms we add is of an even multitude. Note that $p_r$ and its powers are odd and by Euclid, if as many odd numbers as we please are added together, and their multitude is even, then the sum is even.  Thus,$$p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{2k_2},...,p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{2k_r}$$ are even integers. Also, $$2+2^2+...+2^{2k_1}$$ is always even. And so, $$(1+2+2^2+...+2^{2k_1},(1+p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{2k_2}),...,(1+p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{2k_r})$$ are odd integers. Hence, (1+2+2^2+...+2^{2k_1})(1+p_2+p_2^2+...+p_2^{2k_2})...(1+p_r+p_r^2+...+p_r^{2k_r})$$ is odd. This implies that $\sigma(n)$ is odd.

Case 2: Suppose n is twice a perfect square such that $$n=2^{2k_1+1}p_2^{2k_2}...p_r^{2k_r}=2(2^{2k_1}p_2^{2k_2}...p_r^{2k_r})$$. Then, by previous case, $$\sigma(2^{2k_1}p_2^{2k_2}...p_r^{2k_r})$$ is odd. Also, $$\sigma(2)=1+2=3$$. Hence,$$\sigma(n)=\sigma(2^{2k_1+1}p_2^{2k_2}...p_r^{2k_r})$$ is odd.
Therefore, if n is a perfect square or twice a perfect square then $\sigma(n)$is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\sigma (n)$ denotes the sum of all divisors of $n$, we know $$\sigma(n) = (1+p_1+\cdots+p_1^{k_1})(1+p_2+\cdots+p_2^{k_2}) \ldots (1+p_r+\cdots+p_r^{k_r})$$ This is odd if and only if all terms are odd. Suppose $p_1 = 2$ (whether $n$ is even or not doesn't matter, we can just take $k_1=0$ when needed) so the rest of prime factors are odd and thus we need $k_2,\ldots, k_r$ to be even, otherwise we would be adding an even number of odd numbers in some term. Note that, if $k_1$ is $0$ or even, $n$ becomes be a perfect square and if $k_1$ is odd it is twice a square.